# How to send HTTP POST request in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, webclient

I have a remote address here:
http://damp-sands-2243.herokuapp.com/students

I need to insert new students via API call.

Here is how I did it with javasript:

```
var data  = {"name":"Meg",
"regi_number":38};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/students/",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function(){console.log("boo");}
          });
 });
```

You can go to the URL and use your browser's javascript console in order to check whether it works.

Now, my problem is to do the same thing from Xamarin.
Here is what I did,

```
try{
 string data = "{\"name\":\"Meg\",\"regi_number\":38}";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        string reply = client.UploadString("https://damp-sands-2243.herokuapp.com/students/", data);
        // Disply the server's response.
        Console.WriteLine(reply);
}

catch(Exception ex){
       Console.Out.WriteLine("Debug has been started");
       Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.GetType().FullName);
       Console.Out.WriteLine(ex.GetBaseException().ToString());
}
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

> 05-10 15:48:11.644 I/mono-stdout(32078): Debug has been started
>       System.Net.WebException
>       05-10 15:48:11.645 I/mono-stdout(32078): System.Net.WebException
>       System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (422)     Unprocessable Entity .
>       05-10 15:48:11.658 I/mono-stdout(32078): System.Net.WebException: The remote     server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity .
>         at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x0033b] in :0 
>         at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00165] in :0

Comment: You don't seem to set the request header for json content type.

Comment: What do you suggest then?

Comment: `HttpClient` is fully supported by Xamarin platform, so don't use `WebClient`, http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7719/using-httpclient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the error is pretty simple. If you access the page and execute the javascript code in the console you get the following request

```
POST http://damp-sands-2243.herokuapp.com/students/ HTTP/1.1
Host: damp-sands-2243.herokuapp.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-CSRF-Token: jCQqRuqRk4gEK4+rgybQu2+isCvWXI3oZiWsPyrmHF8mportbRS/pBm761rDrQpDv3TI3JICnE40xK59HQCBOA==
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://damp-sands-2243.herokuapp.com/students
Content-Length: 31
Cookie: _restest_session=Yi82UXBXeTdmMjFiT0Rud2tNQTlvRUhxZ0VWRndHeUc4TWZLY3M2ejFtcXorTEw1cWIwb1lNRXdUZDlHWnp2bHpuTlVxL1BYdGg2ckNVM0JDWHZZSUJTS3BWU3BRY0diY3NBSUNBQ0l0MEVLYzZCQjB5Z2syK3pmVUFrazQ3UlhsU1B5OGc0cXk4SzkrY0c5VHdoTkc3RnoxSTIvUWswN3ZrQk5QK1pNNVExcG9Bak1qczV4azRtbVpKaTEzRDgyQkoycGlsdy9qanZLem9RazhEelpqT0dnTXdZZldNS3NXcHhnbC8vd1haaW04NXNGUlpSMVlvT0dGeFQvYWlBSzR5SlFyd3RZN2NIQnNBNDYzYUU0ckE9PS0ta1BPN1ZwczJ1bGE2VnhJT0ZWcUhxUT09--2e9406ef247f597812cd2278422527eb2b679e87; request_method=POST
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"name":"Meg","regi_number":38}
```

As you can see the request contains a cookie and a CSRF-Token. If you don't add them to the request it will give the 422 error that you are facing.

So, firstly you have to make a request to the page, get the cookie and the csrfToken:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string baseSiteString = wc.DownloadString("http://damp-sands-2243.herokuapp.com/students");
string csrfToken = Regex.Match(baseSiteString, "<meta name=\"csrf-token\" content=\"(.*?)\" />").Groups[1].Value;
string cookie = wc.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];
Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", csrfToken);
Console.WriteLine("Cookie: {0}", cookie);
```

The next part is to make the request with all important headers:

```
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
wc.Headers.Add("X-CSRF-Token", csrfToken);
wc.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

string dataString = @"{""name"":""Meg"",""regi_number"":38}";
byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString);
byte[] responseBytes = wc.UploadData(new Uri("https://damp-sands-2243.herokuapp.com/students/"), "POST", dataBytes);
string responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
Console.WriteLine(responseString);
```

That's it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't use token or any kind of whitelist. You can use the exact javascript code in your browser console and try it, my javascript code is working. My question was why the c# code wasn't working.

Comment: @Reza I just edited my answer again. You don't need a custom Webclient for this. you can just grab the cookies from the first request and add it to the second one!

Comment: @Simon How can I setup this kind of header for testing using Postman. I have implemented HMAC in server side. Part of code used in server side is var APPId = autherizationHeaderArray[0]; 
                  var incomingBase64Signature = autherizationHeaderArray[1];                    var nonce = autherizationHeaderArray[2]            var requestTimeStamp = autherizationHeaderArray[3]; 

  var isValid = isValidRequest(req, APPId, incomingBase64Signature, nonce, requestTimeStamp);  I had a look this link https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/pre_request_scripts